# Dynamically adding multiple elements to a web form - drop down menus

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have two drop-down menus in a form that provides options for two different kinds of specifications of a product item.

I want to be able to have an "Add Item" option for users who want more than one product, but each with different specifications. So I basically need the "Add Item" button to generate two or more extra drop-down menus with the original data in them, for a new item. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [clone function](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to make a copy of your dropdown.

So, if you have a div, with an id of `targetDiv`, and you'd like to add to that div a complete copy of a drop down with an id of `originalSelectToCopy` you could say:

```
$("#targetDiv").append($("#originalSelectToCopy").clone());
```

Or, more fluently

```
$("#originalSelectToCopy").clone().appendTo($("#targetDiv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check-out jQuery's `.clone()`: http://api.jquery.com/clone

It allows you to make copies of DOM elements that you can then append to the DOM using: `.append()`, `.appendTo()`, `.replaceWith()`, etc...